# Does count() on Spark mean that all data is already available in memory to be processed?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

My data scenario is as follows:

1. Reading data in a dataframe from database with JDBC using PySpark
2. I make a count() call to both see number of records and also "know" when data load is ready. I am doing this to understand a potential bottleneck.
3. Write to file in s3 (in same region)

So, my objective is to know exactly when all database/table data is loaded, so I can infer if there are problem either reading or writing data when job is getting slow.
In my first attempts, I could get the records number very quick (after 2 min of job running), but my guess is that doing count() does not mean that data is all loaded (in memory).

Answer (score 0):

When you do the `count()` nothing is already loaded, it's a action that will trigger data processing.

if you have a simply logical plan like this :

```
spark.read(..)
.map(..)
.filter(..)
...
.count()
```

the database will be loaded as soon as you call an action (in this exemple `count`)